# my login page disorientates when I switch my device to landscape mode

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation

I just developed a login page activity. If I switch my Android device to landscape, it disorientates my project. Why is this happening?
Below is a screenshot image to show what it looks like.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6Ko9.jpg)